# How to adjust nav bar in small screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a navbar in my page using bootstrap 3,it isn't working well with small screen,the nav bar didn't collapse well when i try to minimize the screen,what is the problem?Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwpefhvf/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <img id="logo" src="../lib/css/images/Logo.jpg" class="pull-left" width="100px" height="100px">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="height: 40px;margin-left: 105px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                 <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" style="height: 30px;margin-top:-12px;">Welcome</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Add New Category</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-2">Search Orders</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-3">Calendar</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-4">Order status</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <?php
                                    if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
                                    {
                                        echo '<a href="../logout.php" id="logout" class="btn btn-success CustLog">Log out</a>';
                                        echo '<h5>Welcome- '.$_SESSION["username"].'</h5>'; 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        header("location:../login.php");
                                    }
                                    include_once "connect.php";
                                ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle doesn't include `bootstrap.js` so the collapse component isn't working. It works fine when both the css and js are included.

http://www.codeply.com/go/VKrQTeUB4v

Comment: Please check the above snapshot for the result i got in my page when i try to minimize the page

Answer (score -1):

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```